# how i can duplicate lines between two txt files

Tags: windows, powershell

i have two files 
first.txt
contains :

```
1  
2
3
4
6
```

Second.txt contains :

```
1
4
2
```

how i can delete all lines in first.txt that contains second.txt lines and save them to third file

Note: second.txt is part of first.txt

Comment: This question seems more coding-related and hence more suited for https://stackoverflow.com/ than Super User.

Comment: Answers to ['Linux tools to treat files as sets and perform set operations on them'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11343/linux-tools-to-treat-files-as-sets-and-perform-set-operations-on-them) in the Unix forum may be helpful. The third file would be the intersection of the first and second. By "second.txt is part of first.txt" do you mean that second.txt is a subset of first.txt?

Answer (score 0):

Verbose

```
$One = Get-Content First.txt
$Two = Get-Content Second.txt
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $One -DifferenceObject $Two |
    select -expand InputObject |
Set Content Out.txt
```

Compact

```
( Compare (gc one.txt) (gc two.txt) ).InputObject | sc Out.txt
```

[Get-Content](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7) retrieves the file contests as an array of lines.

[Compare-Object](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7) does just what its name implies!

Answer (score 0):

here's another way to get the "in 1st, not in 2nd" listing. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- fakes reading in two text files
  when ready to do this for real, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Get-Content` to load the files.
- uses the `.Where()` collection method on the 1st collection to filter out the items that are not in the 2nd collection
- assigns the remaining items to `$ThirdFile`
- displays that on screen

i presume you will have no problem saving the result to a file, so i leave that to you. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$FirstFile = @'
1
2
3
4
6
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
$SecondFile = @'
1
4
2
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#region >>> fake reading in a text file

$ThirdFile = $FirstFile.Where({$_ -notin $SecondFile})

$ThirdFile
```

output ...

```
3
6
```